# To show the two metrics induce the same topology but only one of them is complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

We have a standard metric $d_1(x,y) := |x-y|$ on $\mathbb{R}$, and another metric $d_2(x,y) := |f(x)-f(y)|$ on $\mathbb{R}$, where $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$. I want to show these two metrics induce the same topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but $d_2$ is not complete.

I have no idea about the way to prove "metrics induce the same topology". A hint is to show the identity $id: (\mathbb{R},d_1) \to (\mathbb{R},d_2)$ is a homeomorphism, but I don't understand why the homeomorphic property implies the same topology.

In addition, I know $d_2$ is not complete just by taking a specific sequence like $(x_n = n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, but I want to learn a general proof rather than to use a counter-example.

Comment: To prove that two topologies $\tau_1,\tau_2$ are the same, you should show that every open set in $\tau_1$ is open in $\tau_2$, and that every open set in $\tau_2$ is open in $\tau_1$; this shows that $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$ and $\tau_2\subseteq\tau_1$, so $\tau_1=\tau_2$.

Comment: Topologies are sets, try to prove the double inclusion.

Comment: Regarding the final paragraph: A "general proof" for what statement? A counterexample is a very good proof that something does not have a property of the form "all x are y".

Comment: Your hint to prove that the identity map is a homeomorphism is useful: Since the identity is clearly bijective it only remains to verify that the map is both ways continuous. But pre-images are preserved under continuous maps. Since the map under consideration is the identity map, this would mean that $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$ and $\tau_2\subseteq\tau_1$.

Comment: Two metrics $d_1, d_2$ on a set $R$ are equivalent  (i.e. generate the same topology) iff , for any $x\in R$ and any $r>0$ there exists $r_1>0$ and $r_2>0$ such that (i) $\;B_{d_1}(x,r_1)\subset B_{d_2}(x,r),$ and (ii) $\;B_{d_2}(x,r_2)\subset B_{d_1}(x,r).$

Comment: When $T_i$ is a topology on $X_i$ for $i\in \{1,2\},$ a homeomorphism from $X_1$ to $X_2$ is by definition  a bijection $f:X_1\to X_2$ such that (i) for any $t\in T_1$ the image $f(t)\in T_2, $ and (ii) for any $t'\in Y_2$ the pre-image $f^{-1}(t')\in T_1.$ Equivalently, that $f$ is a continuous bijection whose inverse $f^{-1}$ is also continuous.  In particular when $X_1=X_2,$ the existence of such an $f$ implies $T_1=T_2.$

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I understand that using a counterexample may be a good proof, but in my opinion it contains kinds of techniques based on experience rather than logic.

Comment: @AnalysisNewbie: But the statement you want a proof for is: "There exists a Cauchy sequence in this space which does not converge". I cannot think of a "proof" one could give for this statement which would not essentially consist of constructing such a sequence, i.e. giving an example. How you come up with that sequence might be enlightening, but yes, that might involve experience (analogy) as opposed to pure logic, but that is a huge and valid part of doing math.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's clearer to consider an intermediate space, namely the range of $f$, that is the open interval $(-1,1)$, with its usual metric, and prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism $(\Bbb R, d_1)\to (-1,1)$.

This can be done by directly calculating the inverse of $f$, separating the cases $x\ge0$ and $x<0 $.

The same $f$ as $(\Bbb R, d_2)\to(-1,1)$ is *isometric*, by definition of $d_2$, hence it is also a homeomorphism.

Consequently, $id:(\Bbb R, d_1)\to(\Bbb R, d_2)\ =f^{-1}\circ f$ is also a homeomorphism.

That means that it's continuous, so $d_2$-open sets are also $d_1$-open, and its inverse is continuous, so $d_1$-open sets are also $d_2$-open.